# Array element set pointcut. Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

I just read that it is not possible to define a pointcut on a single array element ([bug link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=157031)). Considering I really need to detect an array element modification, I would like to know if there is any workaround for this kind of problem (a pattern or something).

Something like what is described in [this article](http://jses.seat.org.tw/index.php/jses/article/viewFile/51/29)

```
public class FieldPointcuts {
     static int ar[];

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         ar = new int[] {100}; //set
         ar[0] = 200; //get
     }
}
```

and advice

```
before(int i, Object s, Object[] a):
    arrayset() && args(i, s) && target(a)
{
    System.out.println (" Arrayset:["+i+"/"+(a.length-1)+"] = "+s) ;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing I can think of that will work.  The best that I can think of would be to use Lists instead of arrays, but if you are weaving into third party code, this would not be possible.